# Skip specific id while getting record from database with Entity Framework asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

i want to skip specific record for example i want to skip id umber 10 how i can skip this id using entity framework Skip method.

**Code**

```
int id=10;
DB.Brands.Skip(id).ToList();
```

as we know that it will skip 10 records but i want to skip id number 10 means skip only single id number 10. So any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

could you do this with a `where` statement instead?
Skip is (as you pointed out) used to skip `N` records in a result set.

`DB.Brands.Where(n=>n.id != id).ToList();`

Comment: that,s also way to do that. so that,s not possible with Skip ?

Comment: Maybe with a bit of jumping through hoops but why would you? The where clause is there and ready to do the job.